# Datagridview Header cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
   dgvProductCreation.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell
```

What is this property for (HeaderCell)? and what is the difference between it and Caption (If anyone can show me visually)
Thanks

Comment: Already did , but I did not understand what is the Row header

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Row **HeaderCell** is the "column" on the left of every row...

It can be recognized by '*' special character

The header cell of a row is typically used to display a row label. Users can also click the row header to select the row if the DataGridView.SelectionMode property is set to DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect.

You can set RowHeader property to false if you don't want this in your DataGridView...

screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1z6b.png

http://i263.photobucket.com/albums/ii135/jamesfreddyc/grid1-1.jpg

I think caption is Column's property, not Row's